# Distinguish defective grains from an image of grains

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, classification, feature-detection

I am trying to classify the grains into defective and non-defective using image processing tools like OpenCV in Python. One of the images looks as shown in the figure.

[image: Food Grains]

I first segmented out the grains separately by ranging using HSV space and applied some edge detections algorithms like canny, adaptive threshold but I can find a particular way to resolve this because I recently started exploring and I'm still exploring the power of image processing.

Defective:

[image: Defective_1]  [image: canny_1]                         [image: Defective_2]  [image]     [image]  [image]

Non-Defective:

[image]  [image]   [image]   [image]   [image]  [image]

I have two queries:

1) What metrics to use to distinguish the grains, if I use the edge_detected pictures as shown above.

2) Since the edge detection using canny is failed in the third image of Non-Defective ones.Is there any other features that I could rely on.

Comment: You can try  cv2.InRange  in HSV colorspace for select seeds (background). After you can find  Canny edge or Laplace operator into seeds only. If seed with edge into, then seed is defect.

Comment: @AlexAlex How to find if an edge is inside since the edges are irregular.

Answer (score 3):

By example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img=cv2.imread('YfClv.jpg')
#convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
#color definition
blue_lower = np.array([100,118,33])
blue_upper = np.array([119,255,160])
#blue color mask (sort of thresholding, actually segmentation)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, blue_lower, blue_upper)
se=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (20, 20))
mask=cv2.dilate(mask, se)
mask=cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,300,100) #find edges
out=cv2.bitwise_and(edges, mask) #xor for testing
#cv2.imshow('test', out)
cv2.imwrite('bad_seeds.png', out)
```

Result, inside edges:
[image]